# Unity Game question to check specific position has object or not

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on the game. and I want to know that position (2,2,5) has an object or not?
whenever i place a object at that position it should debug YES.
Please help me to solve my doubt.

Comment: You should explain much more about your problem, with code, screenshots or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use the unity [Physics.CheckSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) method.
The code would look something like this.

```
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(2,2,5);
        float radius = 4f; //Radius to check in;

        if(Physics.CheckSphere(pos,radius))
        {
            //Found
            print("Found Object");
        }
```

You would need to put this in some sort of repeating function I'm guessing. Also it may be important to pass in a LayerMask to the checkSphere method so that you only detect specific objects, not the ground for ex.